# SQL GROUP BY before JOIN - sequence when querying

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    Income.point, Income.date, SUM(out), SUM(inc)
FROM 
    Income 
LEFT JOIN
    Outcome ON Income.point = Outcome.point 
           AND Income.date = Outcome.date
GROUP BY 
    Income.point, Income.date

UNION

SELECT 
    Outcome.point, Outcome.date, SUM(out), SUM(inc)
FROM 
    Outcome 
LEFT JOIN
    Income ON Income.point = Outcome.point 
           AND Income.date = Outcome.date
GROUP BY 
    Outcome.point, Outcome.date;
```

I have this code what I want to do is to group by before joining.
"Assume that we have an SQL query containing joins and a group-by. The standard way of evaluating this type of query is to first perform all the joins and then the group-by operation. However, it may be possible to perform the group-by early, that is, to push the group-by operation past one or more joins. Early grouping may reduce the query processing cost by reducing the amount of data participating in joins."
So I need explanation how to do that

exercise is as follows in this case :

> Under the assumption that the income (inc) and expenses (out) of the money at each outlet (point) are registered any number of times a day, get a result set with fields: outlet, date, expense, income.
>
> Note that a single record must correspond to each outlet at each date.
>
> Use Income and Outcome tables.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Can you try to add some more details to your question?

Comment: If you need to change the SEQUENCE of the results, you need to add an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: SELECT point, date, SUM(out), SUM(inc) FROM (SELECT point, date, out, NULL as inc FROM Outcome UNION ALL SELECT point, date, NULL as out, inc FROM Income ) s GROUP BY point, date ::::::::::::::::::::::::::THAT WORKS so I would say Subquery does the job not ORDER BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
SELECT ip,id,ii,oo FROM
(SELECT I.point ip, I.date id, SUM(I.inc) ii FROM Income I GROUP BY I.point, I.date ) in1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT O.point op, O.date od, SUM(O.out) oo FROM Outcome O GROUP BY O.point, O.date ) ou1 
ON op=ip AND od=id

UNION

SELECT ip,id,ii,oo FROM
(SELECT I.point ip, I.date id, SUM(I.inc) ii FROM Income I GROUP BY I.point, I.date ) in1
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT O.point op, O.date od, SUM(O.out) oo FROM Outcome O GROUP BY O.point, O.date ) ou1 
ON op=ip AND od=id
```

Maybe someone can give it a name too. I don't even know how you call these SELECTS in parentheses ... :-/

**Edit**

Well, taking Luis LL's idea and combining it with "early grouping" one would get the following:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ip,op) point,COALESCE(id,od) date,ii inc,oo out FROM
(SELECT point ip, date id, SUM(inc) ii FROM Income GROUP BY point, date ) in1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT point op, date od, SUM(out) oo FROM Outcome GROUP BY point, date ) ou1 
ON op=ip AND od=id
```

Maybe that will do the trick?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Thank you! But looking up I think Luis LL's solution with `FULL OUTER JOIN` seems to be much more elegant than the UNION I tried.

Comment: The SELECT statements within a FROM clause is called a derived table.

Comment: @qwr, Thanks for this explanation - ten years after I wrote the answer (ROFL)!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to register this data in 2 separate tables (not the most elegant way to do it) you could get away with using subqueries.
A UNION is probably not the way to do it, since that does not put the datasets of each 'point' together in one record.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what do you want to achieve, but in my opinion what you need is `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(Income.point, OutCome.point) AS Point, ISNULL(Income.date, OutComeDate) AS [date], SUM(out) AS Expenses, SUM(inc) AS Income
FROM Income 
FULL OUTER JOIN Outcome 
    ON Income.point = Outcome.point AND Income.date = Outcome.date
GROUP BY Income.point, Income.date
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you could use CTE.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT [point]
    ,      [date]
    ,      [SumOut] = SUM([out])
    ,      [SumInc] = SUM([inc])
    FROM Income 
    GROUP BY [point], [date]
)

SELECT CTE.[Point]
,      CTE.[Date]
,      CTE.[SumOut]
,      CTE.[SumInc]
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN Outcome ON CTE.[point] = Outcome.point AND CTE.[date] = Outcome.[date]
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT A.* FROM
(SELECT Income.point, Income.date, SUM(out), SUM(inc)
FROM 
    Income 
LEFT JOIN
    Outcome ON Income.point = Outcome.point 
           AND Income.date = Outcome.date
GROUP BY 
    Income.point, Income.date) A

UNION

SELECT B.* FROM
(SELECT Outcome.point, Outcome.date, SUM(out), SUM(inc)
FROM 
    Outcome 
LEFT JOIN
    Income ON Income.point = Outcome.point 
           AND Income.date = Outcome.date
GROUP BY 
    Outcome.point, Outcome.date) B;

Answer (score -1):

```
Select  ip,id,oo,ii from(
Select i.point as ip,i.date as id,sum(i.inc) as ii from Income as I group BY i.point, i.date) in1

Left join (
Select o.point as op, o.date as od,sum(o.out) as oo from outcome as O group by o.point, o.date) ou1
on ip=op and id=od

union

Select  op,od,oo,ii from(
Select o.point as op, o.date as od,sum(o.out) as oo from outcome as O group by o.point, o.date) ou2

Left join (
Select i.point as ip,i.date as id,sum(i.inc) as ii from Income as I group BY i.point, i.date) in2
on ip=op and id=od
```